# Node Webkit change DOM element from Node

Tags: node-webkit

My target is to show real time values in a graph, what I read from Serial port. For that, have to send values **from Node side to DOM side**. referring Node Webkit  documentation I found to way access function in Node from DOM but I couldn't find a way to acess other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this, if you use mix mode, you can use both DOM and NODE together in same javascript file, to change your mode mixed-context

```
"chromium-args": "--mixed-context",
```

here is the example main package.json file looks like

```
{
  "name": "abc-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "chromium-args": "--mixed-context",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nw src/",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-serialport": "^2.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "nw": "^0.45.5"
  }
}
```